# Firebase issue, I need to take out values from first two nodes

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I try to achieve the following: When count is changed to "2" I need the function to push the JSON, named "updates", to the specific place in database, and take names from PlayerQueue node (0:"Mik", 1:"Bg" etc.) and put it into the database as "id". So the thing is that I need it to take first two nodes (0 and 1 in this case) and take names out of it (Mik and Bg) and put them in the database as id1 and id2 (in this database I have only one id value but I will add it later), the issue is that I can't figure out how to take out names from the first two nodes.

**My database:**

[image: click here to veiw my database]

And here is my code

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
import { resolve } from 'url';
//Game/queue/{queueId}/PlayerCount
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);


exports.createGame = functions.database.ref('Game/queue/PlayerCount').onUpdate((change, context) => {

  const ref1 = admin.database().ref('/Game/queue/PlayerQueue').limitToFirst(1);
  var tmp:String = 'esh';
  ref1.once("value")
  .then(result => {

         tmp = result.val();
         console.log(tmp)


  var updates = {};
  updates['id'] = tmp
  updates['visible'] = {
    place: 'a1',
    sign: 'rock'
  };



  const after = change.after.val();

  if(after.count == 2){
    return admin.database().ref('/Game/allGames').push(updates);
  }  
  return null

}).catch(reason => {
  console.log(reason)
});  

  return null;

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're looking for the first two child nodes in the queue, you should order by their ID and then limit to getting 2 children:

```
const query = admin.database().ref('/Game/queue/PlayerQueue').orderByKey().limitToFirst(2);
```

Then you can listen for the value:

```
query.once("value").then(snapshot => {
  snapshot.forEach(child => {
    console.log(child.key+": "+child.val());
  });
});
```

The above purely solves the "getting the first two child nodes".

**Update**: to get the two children into separate variables, you can do something like this:

```
query.once("value").then(snapshot => {
  var first, second;
  snapshot.forEach(child => {
    console.log(child.key+": "+child.val());
    if (!first) {
      first = child.val();
    }
    else if (!second) {
      second = child.val();
    }
  });
  if (first && second) {
    // TODO: do something with first and second
  }
});
```

Comment: well here is the thing, id-s of those nodes will be completely random, will it work then??

Comment: Could you please tell, how can I take those two values separately??

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "separately" there. If you're asking how to extract the two into separate variables, I'd loop over the children and assign them in there.

Comment: yes, that's exactly what I want, I just can't figure out how can I do that in forEach loop, can you show??

Comment: I added an example of that. Make sure to understand it exactly before you copy/paste, as this is a fairly basic programming construct.

Answer (score 0):

Use Firestore unless you have a valid reason to use the Realtime Database.

See Cloud Firestore triggers documentation on how to take action `.onUpdate` to `qty 2`. See [documentation example](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events#trigger_a_function_when_a_document_is_updated) below

> ```
> exports.updateUser = functions.firestore
>     .document('users/{userId}')
>     .onUpdate((change, context) => {
>       // Get an object representing the document
>       // e.g. {'name': 'Marie', 'age': 66}
>       const newValue = change.after.data();
>
>       // ...or the previous value before this update
>       const previousValue = change.before.data();
>
>       // access a particular field as you would any JS property
>       const name = newValue.name;
>
>       // perform desired operations ...
>     });
> ```

Comment: I have a valid reason to use Realtime Database.